# Best way to list simple cycles on graph that have no subsets that are simple cycles?

Tags: algorithm, graph

so I want a list of simple cycles on a undirected, unweighted graph such that no cycle has a subset that is another cycle on the graph.

One way I have considered doing this was to just list all simple cycles and then and then filter them after, but I thought that this would take a long time on a densely connected graph with many short cycles. Is there an algorithm to do it as you go instead of reducing afterwards?

To illustrate my problem, I made this image:
[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5FXt.png)
.

From this graph, I would want to find the following cycles

- ABD
- BCE
- EHG
- GFD
- DBEG
- CIHE

But NOT any of these cycles

- ABEDG
- IGHEC
- FDBEG

If it makes the problem simpler, A list of all the cycles as described above with length greater than three would also suffice. This would return only DBEG and CIHE from the graph above.